# Hacer dos count agrupados por el mismo criterio

Tags: mysql

Hola estoy intentando contar las filas por medio de joins entre 3 tablas es decir la tabla principal es pacientes, y quiero contar las compras de estos pacientes en la tabla de ventas, y aparte tengo otra tabla llamada sms en el cual quiero contar los registros donde aparecen estos pacientes

```
SELECT COUNT(v.TarjetaID), COUNT(s.id_cliente)   from 
paciente p JOIN venta v ON p .TarjetaID  = v.TarjetaID join Sms s on s.id_cliente =p.ID 
group by v.TarjetaID,s.id_cliente
```

pero me esta esta devolviendo el mismo resultado en ambas columnas, es decir si pone 10 en la de ventas en la de sms ponen al parecer los mismos 10, no entiendo que debería hacer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las 3 tablas entonces, lo que no logro hacer es contar la cantidad de ventas por paciente, y la cantidad de sms por paciente todo en una misma consulta, ya que parece que al hacer los joins repite los campos

Comment: Sin ver sobre qué datos trabaja tu ejemplo y cuál debería ser la salida, es complicado. Cualquier consulta es válida dependiendo de lo que desees.

Comment: Sin ahondar mucho en el tema creo que tu problema es que no estas usando ningún tipo de Join (Cross, Left, Right, Inner),  mira este pequeño [tutorial](https://guru99.es/joins/).